# Coequalizers in the category of categories

Tags: category-theory

What form do coequalizers have in the category of categories ? An explicit description would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

[This paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.62.7120&rep=rep1&type=pdf) give a complete description of coequalizers in $\mathbf{Cat}$ (the category of small categories). See page 22.